# Bash one-liner code to output unique values

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have this command which will output 0, 1 or 2.

This line of code is part of a config file (zabbix), only reason for one-liner code.

```
mysql -u root -e  "show slave status\G" | \
grep -E 'Slave_IO_Running:|Slave_SQL_Running:' | cut -f2 -d':' | \
sed "s/No/0/;s/Yes/1/" | awk '{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM }'
```

But I want it to output values to be like this so I can setup alert with correct status:

> If only `Slave_IO_Running` is `No` then output 1.
>
> If only `Slave_SQL_Running` is `No` then output 2.
>
> If both are `Yes` then output 3.
>
> If both are `No` then output 0.
>
> If no lines/output from `show slave status` command then output 4.

So something like modify first entry of `No` with a unique value using sed or awk. And second entry with unique value and so on.

Output of show slave status\G

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.10.10.10
                  Master_User: replicationslave
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.009081
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 856648307
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.002513
                Relay_Log_Pos: 1431694
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.009081
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

Comment: Can you include the output of just the `mysql -u root -e  "show slave status\G"` command, so that we have a better idea of what data you're manipulating, and can test the solutions we might come up with?

Comment: You can use `if` statements without having to run the query twice, variables exist for a reason.

Comment: Note, if you end a line with a pipe, you don't need the line-continuation backslash -- bash knows you're not done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all the string processing here in `awk`:

```
mysql -u root -e  "show slave status\G" | awk 'BEGIN {output=0} /Slave_IO_Running.*No/ {output+=1} /Slave_SQL_Running.*No/ {output +=2} END {if(output==3}{print 0} else {if(output==0} {print 3} else {print output}}'
```

This will start the output counter at `0`, if we match `Slave_IO_Running` with `No` we'll add 1.  If we match `Slave_SQL_Running` with `No` we'll add 2, then at the end we'll print the total, which will be 0 if neither are matched, 1 if only IO is No, 2 if only SQL is No and 3 if both are No.  Since you want to print `0` if both are Yes we reverse our count at the end, if we got a 3 then both were "No" so print 0, otherwise if it was 0 print 3, else print its own value.

Comment: Some explanation of your answer would be lovely.

Comment: @ghoti was already underweigh, though I then saw the edit to the question about wanting 3 if both are yes and had to fix things a bit

Comment: Thank you. You first edit was still okay I think. If both were yes, it returned 0. Its  3 if both were No. I'm actually using your first edit. Correct me if I should updated one. I don't mind which number but the values have to be unique so I can assign each value to a status.

Comment: If you don't mind whether it's 0 or 3, then I'd go with the first one, it's simpler

Comment: Edit suggested to include "else if (NR==0) print 4;" because if there is no output due to any issues we can print 4.

Comment: mysql -u root -e  "slave status\G" 2>/dev/null | awk 'BEGIN {output=0} /Slave_IO_Running.*No/ {output+=1} /Slave_SQL_Running.*No/ {output +=2} END {if(output==3) print 0; else if (NR==0) print 4; else if(output==0) print 3; else print output}'

Answer (score 2):

The following awk code could be compacted into a single line if you feel the urge to do that:

```
awk -F: -v ret=0 '
  /Slave_IO_Running:.*No/ { ret=1 }
  /Slave_IO_Running:.*Yes/ { yes++ }
  /Slave_SQL_Running:.*No/ { ret=(ret==1) ? 0 : 2 }
  /Slave_SQL_Running:.*Yes/ { yes++ }
  END { print (yes==2) ? 3 : ret }
'
```

No `grep` or `cut` or `sed` is required, this takes the output of your mysql command directly. It also assumes that `Slave_IO_Running` will always appear before `Slave_SQL_Running` in the output of your command.

The notation in the third line and last line functions as an in-line "if" statement -- if the value of `ret` equals `1`, set `ret` to `0`; otherwise set `ret` to `2`.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have name to value pairs in your data it's usually clearest, simplest and easiest to enhance later to first create an array mapping the names to the values and then access the values by their names, e.g.:

```
awk '
{ f[$1]=$2 }
END {
    if (f["Slave_10_Running:"] == "Yes")
        rslt = (f["Slave_SQL_Running:"] == "Yes" ? 3 : 2)
    else
        rslt = (f["Slave_SQL_Running:"] == "Yes" ? 1 : 0)
    print rslt
}
' file
1
```