# awk if else statement syntax error. What is causing it?

Tags: awk

There's a syntax error in awk if else statement which I got the code from another question and unable to fix it. 
[Bash one-liner code to output unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45613535/bash-one-liner-code-to-output-unique-values).

Can someone correct the statement.

```
awk 'BEGIN {output=0} /Slave_IO_Running.*No/ {output+=1} /Slave_SQL_Running.*No/ {output +=2} END {if(output==3} {print 0} else {if(output==0} {print 3} else {print output}}'
```

debug output

```
awk 'BEGIN {output=0} /Slave_IO_Running.*No/ {output+=1} /Slave_SQL_Running.*No/ {output +=2} END {if(output==3}{print 0} else {if(output==0} {print 3} else {print output}}'
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {output=0} /Slave_IO_Running.*No/ {output+=1} /Slave_SQL_Running.*No/ {output +=2} END {if(output==3}{print 0} else {if(output==0} {print 3} else {print output}}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {output=0} /Slave_IO_Running.*No/ {output+=1} /Slave_SQL_Running.*No/ {output +=2} END {if(output==3}{print 0} else {if(output==0} {print 3} else {print output}}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                      ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {output=0} /Slave_IO_Running.*No/ {output+=1} /Slave_SQL_Running.*No/ {output +=2} END {if(output==3}{print 0} else {if(output==0} {print 3} else {print output}}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {output=0} /Slave_IO_Running.*No/ {output+=1} /Slave_SQL_Running.*No/ {output +=2} END {if(output==3}{print 0} else {if(output==0} {print 3} else {print output}}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                                    ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {output=0} /Slave_IO_Running.*No/ {output+=1} /Slave_SQL_Running.*No/ {output +=2} END {if(output==3}{print 0} else {if(output==0} {print 3} else {print output}}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                                                       ^ syntax error
```

Comment: Laying out your code with newlines and proper indenting makes these simple typos much easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

`if(output==0}` and `if(output==3}` should end with close paren `)`, not close brace `}`.

You should use `else if` for nested if statements, and those braces are only necessary for multiple operations.

```
END {if(output==3) print 0; else if(output==0) print 3; else print output}
```

Just for fun:

```
END {print output==3? 0: output==0? 3: output}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are clues in the error messages, e.g.:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: ... END {if(output==3}{print 0} else {if(output==0} {print 3} else {print output}}
awk: cmd. line:1:                      ^ syntax error
```

It really couldn't be much clearer.